# How to inject values to a wicket page using spring?

Tags: spring, wicket

Is it possible to inject a value to a wicket page using spring?

With `@Value` it's possible to inject values to a spring bean.

I know the `@SpringBean` annotation, but this is only for beans.

My workaround is to wrap the value with a spring bean and then inject this with `@SpringBean` to my wicket page. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can use @Value to inject values.

Comment: @CodeFreak: Yes, to inject into spring beans, but not into a wicket page, like i asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this problem using getter & setter in our custom child of `WebApplication`. This child is standard Spring bean and is configured in spring's configuration.

Otherwise you have to create some "config" bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Wicket resource loader to load spring values, and then those values will be resolved like regular wicket messages. If instead you need it within the body of the wicket class to do some business logic, that may be an opportunity to refactor that logic outside of the view layer.

Here's what the resource loader looks like:

```
public class SpringPropertiesResourceLoader
    implements IStringResourceLoader
{

    public SpringPropertiesResourceLoader()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public String loadStringResource(Class<?> clazz, String key, Locale locale, String style, String variation)
    {
        return loadStringResource(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String loadStringResource(Component component, String key, Locale locale, String style, String variation)
    {
        return loadStringResource(key);
    }

    private String loadStringResource(String key)
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationContext applicationContext =  WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebPortalApplication.get().getServletContext());
            ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            String rv = beanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue("${" + key + "}");
            return rv;
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException iae)
        {
            // no property with the name - move along
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then add that to your application in `init()`:

```
    getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(new SpringPropertiesResourceLoader());
```